# How do I add a Map Activity to a fragment and obtain the location of the nearest hospital?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-maps

I have an empty fragment where I want to add a Google View map which can find the location of the nearest hospital. I have no clue how to do this.

Here is the code for the empty fragment:

```
package com.iotaconcepts.aurum;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class TwoFragment extends Fragment
{

    public TwoFragment()
    {

        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial will be useful for you to get started with your MAP Fragment

http://www.joellipman.com/articles/google/android/application-development/android-os-add-googlemap-as-fragment.html

And for finding the hospitals near you you can use the following tutorial

http://javapapers.com/android/find-places-nearby-in-google-maps-using-google-places-apiandroid-app/